# Non google-playstore based community android-app rating website

Tags: applications, app-ratings

Is there any comunity based android-app rating web site where the app-popularity is not based on google-playstore?

The sites i found so far either indirectly uses google-playstore-ranking or some technical writer tells you "wich are the best XXX apps for YYY".

I am interested in community based ranking where even apps that are not available in google-playstore can be ranked.

I am thinking of something similar to *.stackexchange where registered user can either

- up and downvote apps
- or give an app a quality value (i.e. 1-5 stars)

Answer (score 0):

I found https://www.slant.co/tags/android:

- users can ask subjective questions.

  - i.e. What is the best android app for xxx
- users can give subjective answers.

  - i.e. The yyy app is a good candidate
- users can add subjective pro and contra arguments.

  - i.e. contra: the yyy app consumes to much energy

The community can add more answers and pro/contra arguments and rate each seperatly.